# Invalid PNG Image file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk

Tags: html, objective-c, ipad, png, javax.imageio

I have some HTML content pages in an app and I'm using a UIWebView to display them.  Some of these pages have a PNG image in them that is generating the following message in the debug console in xcode:

```
ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk
```

The image still displays and looks correct.  Also this only happens when I run the app on an iPad (3rd generation).  My iPhone 4 doesn't display this message.

My first thought was that it was caused by a ~ character in the filename (I've added the ~ipad tag to the filename).  However, removing the ~ character doesn't have any effect.

I've done a google search but I only get 3 results.  2 of them are in Chinese that doesn't seem to be translated well by Google's translater.  The other results seems to be someone with the same issue as me, but no responses to his [post](http://www.1771.in/ios-funny-display-issue-with-ipad-3-retina-display-says-quotidot-doesnt-point-to-valid-idat-chunkquot.html).

Comment: Is it a very large image (dimension wise)?

Comment: I'm not sure if you would consider it very large or not.  It's 742px by 261px

Comment: TweakPNG is a little program, useful to peek inside the PNG structure: http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/

Comment: Thanks @leonbloy, the TweakPNG program seems like it would be quite useful.  Unfortunately I don't see a difference between a PNG image that works vs one that displays the error.

Answer (score 12):

Had the same problem. Solution:
use "color sync utility" which is a standard program, you can load from launchpad. Open the png file and save it with the utility.

Comment: Did either of you have to do anything other than just open the PNG file and re-save it?  I gave this a try (with a Clean before a rebuild) but I still get the message in the debug console. @btype

Comment: Nope, just open and re-save. In my case the image was displayed only on half the screen.

Comment: I opened with color sync, saved it, and I still get the error. This is the image I used: http://lcolumbus.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/big-data-drives-rapid-changes.jpg

Comment: I have hundreds of assets. How do I tell which file has the problem?

Answer (score 4):

'cleaning' the project (xcode menu path : product -> clean) solved this exact issue for me.

Resaving the .png with a new name did not.

Image did appear in the simulator but not on the test device (ipod touch 5th gen.)

Very large image 4000 x 4000

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, I had the exact same issue just about an hour ago. I didn't find a particular reason for why it was failing, but I think I was able to "fix" the image to make it display properly and not throw an error.

I just opened it in Preview and exported a new PNG file from the source. Once I replaced the bad image in my project file with the newly created one, I cleaned, compiled and it worked as expected.

Hope it's as easy as that for you...

Comment: Unfortunately that solution didn't fix it for me.

Comment: Worked for me. The image was only displayed on half the screen, and after re-saving it, was displayed properly.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check you don't have another file with the same name in another directory. That is what caused this error for me .. (duplicate Default.png)

Comment: I had a similar problem. I had revised an image. I first deleted the old image from the project and then added the revised one in. When testing I got this error and the "new" image would not display. I cleaned the project and the error was resolved and the image was displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my app.It turn out that the images that the user was uploading to my server and edited with php +imagemagik where striped out.I was using the following command to edit the uploaded image:

```
convert $uploadfile -resize 300x300 -quality 30 -strip $uploadfile
```

When i removed the `-strip` parameter the error was disappeared !

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here.
1 - Close XCode;
2 - Open the image in Photoshop;
3 - Re-save ( replace the same image ) with 80% quality;
4 - Open XCode, clean it `CMD + SHIFT + K`;
5 - Build it in your device again;

Very simple and work for me.
And for you ?